# Summing specific columns for each row in a matrix of double

Tags: matlab, for-loop, matrix, nested-forms

I would like to sum specific columns of each row in a matrix using a for loop. Below I have included a simplified version of my problem. As of right now, I am calculating the column sums individually, but this is not effective as my actual problem has multiple matrices (data sets).

```
a = [1 2 3 4 5 6; 4 5 6 7 8 9];
b = [2 2 3 4 4 6; 3 3 3 4 5 5];
% Repeat the 3 lines of code below for row 2 of matrix a
% Repeat the entire process for matrix b
c = sum(a(1,1:3));                   % Sum columns 1:3 of row 1
d = sum(a(1,4:6));                   % Sum columns 4:6 of row 1
e = sum(a(1,:));                     % Sum all columns of row 1
```

I would like to know how to create a for loop that automatically loops through and sums the specific columns of each row for each matrix that I have.

Thank you.

Comment: `sum(a(:,1:3),2)` etc. using the second input of `sum` to indicate dimension to sum over?

Comment: Hi @David, I forgot to mention that my matrix is of double format, so the code that you indicated does not give me the correct answer. Any idea on how to proceed? Thank you.

Comment: I don't understand, in you code in your question both `a` and `b` are vectors of doubles.

Comment: Hi @David, my bad. What I meant to say was that, lets say I generate a random matrix `g = rand(37,100)` to which I then use `sum(g(:, 1:50), 37)`, the result would somehow be in 37 x 50 matrix. What I want is a **37 x 1 matrix**, that is each row represents the sum of columns 1:50 for each row in the matrix.

Comment: How do you define the groups of columns that should be summed? Currently their indices are hard-coded. Do you have some variable that defines the groups?

Comment: @Kendo96 no you still do `sum(g(:,1:50),2)` in that case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a solution that you don't need to use `for` loop.

Assuming that you have a matrix `a` of size `2x12`, and you want to do the row sums every `4` columns, then you can use `reshape()` and `squeeze()` to get the final result:

```
k = 4;
a = [1:12
     13:24];
% a =
%    1    2    3    4    5    6    7    8    9   10   11   12
%   13   14   15   16   17   18   19   20   21   22   23   24

s = squeeze(sum(reshape(a,size(a,1),k,[]),2));
```

and you will get

```
s =

   10   26   42
   58   74   90
```

Comment: @ChelseaG. Okey, I got it, you have unequal-sized chunks for slicing your matrix. Do you have any rule about slicing? After knowing that it would be easier for me to edit my answer

Comment: Thank you @ThomasIsCoding for your help. What you presented is what I actually want. I just noticed my mistake with the uneven amount of columns and will correct the original posted question above. Sorry for all the confusion caused.

Comment: @Kendo96 Great!

Comment: @Kendo96 Also, I saw you also need the row sum over all columns. I guess you know how to do that, i.e., `sum(a,2)`, so I did not put it in my code. If you think my answer fixed your problem and your are happy with it, so please accept it by clicking the tick under the vote, then your post will be treated as "answered" in SO. Thanks!